# Pandas dataframe.value_counts().keys() with float indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas in order to obtain the value_counts.  When issuing the command:

```
my_variable.value_counts().keys()
```

I get the following output:

> Index([1.0, 0.0, 1.00999999046, 2.0, 2.00999999046, 3.0,
>   1.01000022888, 3.00999999046, 4.00999999046, 4.0, 6.00999999046, 5.00999999046, 8.00999999046, 2.01000022888, 5.0, 0.990000009537, 9.00999999046, 6.0, 7.0, 12.0099999905, 7.00999999046, 10.0099999905, 3.01000022888, 19.0199999809, 11.0099999905, 20.0199999809, 8.0, 14.0199999809, 4.01000022888, 5.01000022888, 38.0399999619, 46.0499999523, 40.0399999619, 20.0299999714, 16.0199999809, 18.0299999714, 9.01999998093, 11.0199999809, 21.0199999809, -10651.4099998, -4643.13999987, -6388.92000008, -5779.98000002], dtype=object)

The question is, how do I access the keys that are made up of floating point values, such as key 1.00999999046?

I can access the index 1.0 by using:

```
my_variable.value_counts()[1]
```

but, if I attempt

```
my_variable.value_counts()[1.00999999046]
```

then I get an error stating:

> KeyError: 1.00999999046

I believe that it may be something related to the fact that the dytpe=object for the index, but I don't know what to do in order to account for this.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want exactly the count for a specifc key? You can do this `my_variable.value_counts().loc[1.00999999046]`

Comment: the problem is that there are more decimals than are shown; try `my_variable.round(decimals=11).value_counts()[1.00999999046]`

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the exact count for each key in my index.  I obviously do not need 11 decimal places, and agree that there are probably more unshown decimals.  Unfortunately, I still get a key error with both of the above lines.  I have found a better approach to my overall problem, but I'm still a little curious how to access these fields in a case like this.  Thank you both for your input so far.

Comment: Also possible to value_count with bins aka cut (or qcut). Usually helps to describe overall problem - why you want to do something as well as what it is you're doing

Comment: Float indexers are supported much better in >= 0.13 (you will see that output as Float64Index).

Comment: Andy, ultimately, I just wanted to be able to get a count for all values that are less than 1.01 seconds.  This can be accomplished more easily by doing the following:  

count = len( my_variable[my_variable <- 1.01] )

But, as I mentioned, I'm still curious how I would go about accessing one of those specific indexes should I need one in the future.  I've been reading about the bins, and that could be a way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

This works just fine in >= 0.13. Prior to 0.13 Float Indicies were not anything special. They have logic now to avoid the rounding / truncation of indexers to integers. in-other-works the values are looked up as is, not coerced at all (for Float64Index). In fact this is the point of this type of index, to make a uniform indexing model with `[],ix,loc` returning the same exact results.

See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#float64index)

```
In [8]: i = Index([1.0, 0.0, 1.00999999046, 2.0, 2.00999999046, 3.0, 1.01000022888, 3.00999999046, 4.00999999046, 4.0, 6.00999999046, 5.00999999046, 8.00999999046, 2.01000022888, 5.0, 0.990000009537, 9.00999999046, 6.0, 7.0, 12.0099999905, 7.00999999046, 10.0099999905, 3.01000022888, 19.0199999809, 11.0099999905, 20.0199999809, 8.0, 14.0199999809, 4.01000022888, 5.01000022888, 38.0399999619, 46.0499999523, 40.0399999619, 20.0299999714, 16.0199999809, 18.0299999714, 9.01999998093, 11.0199999809, 21.0199999809, -10651.4099998, -4643.13999987, -6388.92000008, -5779.98000002])

In [9]: i
Out[9]: Float64Index([1.0, 0.0, 1.00999999046, 2.0, 2.00999999046, 3.0, 1.01000022888, 3.00999999046, 4.00999999046, 4.0, 6.00999999046, 5.00999999046, 8.00999999046, 2.01000022888, 5.0, 0.990000009537, 9.00999999046, 6.0, 7.0, 12.0099999905, 7.00999999046, 10.0099999905, 3.01000022888, 19.0199999809, 11.0099999905, 20.0199999809, 8.0, 14.0199999809, 4.01000022888, 5.01000022888, 38.0399999619, 46.0499999523, 40.0399999619, 20.0299999714, 16.0199999809, 18.0299999714, 9.01999998093, 11.0199999809, 21.0199999809, -10651.4099998, -4643.13999987, -6388.92000008, -5779.98000002], dtype='object')

In [10]: s = Series(i.tolist() * 3)


In [13]: s.value_counts()[1.00999999046]
Out[13]: 3
```

Note that the display of the index is of a truncated view of the values (they fully exist, just don't print out beyond 2 places here)

```
In [14]: s.value_counts().sort_index()
Out[14]: 
-10651.41    3
-6388.92     3
-5779.98     3
-4643.14     3
 0.00        3
 0.99        3
 1.00        3
 1.01        3
 1.01        3
 2.00        3
 2.01        3
 2.01        3
 3.00        3
 3.01        3
 3.01        3
 4.00        3
 4.01        3
 4.01        3
 5.00        3
 5.01        3
 5.01        3
 6.00        3
 6.01        3
 7.00        3
 7.01        3
 8.00        3
 8.01        3
 9.01        3
 9.02        3
 10.01       3
 11.01       3
 11.02       3
 12.01       3
 14.02       3
 16.02       3
 18.03       3
 19.02       3
 20.02       3
 20.03       3
 21.02       3
 38.04       3
 40.04       3
 46.05       3
dtype: int64

In [15]: s.value_counts()[1.00999999046]
Out[15]: 3

In [16]: s.value_counts().keys()
Out[16]: Float64Index([3.00999999046, 14.0199999809, 2.00999999046, -10651.4099998, 2.01000022888, 18.0299999714, 20.0299999714, 16.0199999809, 6.00999999046, 3.01000022888, 8.0, 11.0199999809, 19.0199999809, 7.0, 1.01000022888, 0.990000009537, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 46.0499999523, 11.0099999905, 12.0099999905, 4.00999999046, 40.0399999619, 7.00999999046, 9.01999998093, 6.0, -6388.92000008, 21.0199999809, 38.0399999619, 5.0, 20.0199999809, 4.01000022888, -5779.98000002, 1.00999999046, 9.00999999046, -4643.13999987, 5.01000022888, 10.0099999905, 8.00999999046, 5.00999999046, 0.0], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value_counts().index[i]` instead. `i` is the number of index that you wanted to call.

Comment: i mean value_counts().index[i]

Comment: Instead of commenting changes, you should directly edit your answer with the correct information.