# Pandas Value counts showing same bin twice

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Python and Pandas.

I have a large `DataFrame` on which I am running `value_counts` on to check the output as follows:

```
df['Remaining'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Below is the output, as you can see `50.0` appears twice, once `6817` times and once 4 times. I tried exporting the out when remaining `df['Remaining'] == 50` to see the difference but there no difference really. Anything I am doing wrong?

```
-225.0        2
-200.0        4
-150.0       14
-125.0        7
-100.0      346
-75.0       202
-50.0      1343
-25.0       527
 0.0      61167
 25.0     10467
 50.0      6817
 50.0         4
 75.0      5358
 100.0     3428
 125.0     1626
 150.0      598
 175.0      334
 200.0      223
 225.0      102
 250.0       69
 275.0       13
 350.0        1
 375.0        4
 400.0        3
 425.0        2
Name: Remaining steps, dtype: int64
```

Comment: what is the dtype of the `Remaining` column? also can you post results of `df['Remaining'].unique()`

Answer (score 3):

Without your data, I'll try to make a guess. I think it is precision-point issue. Your 2 different `50.0` bins may actually have different precision-point values, and the print-out doesn't show it. Let's try this sample

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [-12.5, 50.00000000004, 50.0, -25.10, 50.0]} , dtype=float)
print(df)

In [23]: 
    num
0 -12.5
1  50.0
2  50.0
3 -25.1
4  50.0
```

Print just show the round-up value. Let's try `value_counts`. It shows 2 identical `50.0` bins the same as your issue

```
df.num.value_counts().sort_index()

Out[27]:
-25.1    1
-12.5    1
 50.0    2
 50.0    1
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

Let's try `round` it up before `value_counts`

```
df.num.round(2).value_counts().sort_index()

Out[28]:
-25.1    1
-12.5    1
 50.0    3
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

So, I guess you may call `round` before `value_counts` on your series as above to see it is fixed.

Comment: @anky_91: thanks, bro. It is still a guess until OP confirms :)

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to use the example dataframe from @Andy L..

Just a quick dirty way of achieving the same would be..

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [-12.5, 50.00000000004, 50.0, -25.10, 50.0]} , dtype=float)
>>> df
    num
0 -12.5
1  50.0
2  50.0
3 -25.1
4  50.0
```

### Output:

```
>>> df['num'].astype(str).value_counts()
50.0     3
-25.1    1
-12.5    1
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

If it looks to be a precision issue, you could try setting.

As we can see in our data frame Structure the precision point is deferring for `50` where we can see the float precision for initial `50.0` occuring twice and for another its once as `50.00000000004`, hence `value_counts()` segregates them as an individual bin.

```
>>> df.num.value_counts().keys()
Float64Index([50.0, -25.1, 50.00000000004, -12.5], dtype='float64')
```

As i said, so either we can set precision point which we want count upto as follows..

```
>>> pd.set_option('precision', 0)
```

OR

```
>>> df['num'].map('{:,.2f}'.format).value_counts()
50.00     3
-12.50    1
-25.10    1
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

You can see the explanation from Pandas developer @jeff [From this SO thread about float precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410417/pandas-dataframe-value-counts-keys-with-float-indexes)

hope this will help.